# How to import routes in polka js similar to express.Route()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to import route logic from another file. In express js this is achievable via express.Route(), when i tried polka.Route() an error pops up saying Route doesn't exist in polka.

**Express Implementation**

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const app = express();    
app.use('/users', users);
```

**user.js**

```
const express = require('express');    
const router = express.Router();    
router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({ msg: 'works' }));    
module.exports = router;
```

When `/users/test` is hit the output is {msg:'works'}. This works for the express implementation. For the polka implementation i changed the word `express` to `polka` installing it. The issue arises on the line polka.Router() of user.js. How do i enable this functionality of importing route logic from another file in polka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `polka` micro web server does not implement a difference between routers and the app. In your `users.js` file simply setup your routes as you would in your `server.js` file and then `module.export`. See Below:

Polka Implementation

**server.js**

```
const polka = require('polka');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const app = polka();    
app.use('/users', users);
```

**user.js**

```
const polka = require('polka');    
const router = polka();    
router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.end(JSON.stringify({ msg: 'works' })));    
module.exports = router;
```

Hope this help!

Also, here is a good link to see other differences between `Express.js` and `Polka.js`: https://github.com/lukeed/polka#comparisons

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer it works. How ever it says res.json is not part of polka . How do i send json from polka

Comment: My apologies. I updated the answer return JSON properly in using Polka. You have use `res.end()` and pass a String.

Comment: Also, polka.js providers a nice extension package `@polka/send-type` for responses of various different types. See: https://github.com/lukeed/polka/tree/master/packages/send-type